# How do I allow Plotly bar text to overflow past bar?

Tags: r, layout, plotly, bar-chart, r-plotly

How do I get the **text size** for dr5 and dr3 for the shorter bars? If the text is longer than the bar span, I would like the text to overflow past the end of the bar.

I tried using uniformtext in layout, but that shrunk all text to the smallest font being used. How do I change all font to the biggest size being used?

[image: barchart]

```
library(plotly)

# Test long text and short bars
xValues <- c("loooooooooooooooooonnnnnngg","lonnnnnnnnnnggggggg",
             "dr3","dr4","dr5")
yValues <- c(0.5,1,2,0.22,10)

bar <- plot_ly(x = yValues,
               y = xValues) %>% 
       add_trace(
               type = 'bar',
               orientation = 'h',
               text = xValues,
               textangle = 360,
               textposition = "inside",
               insidetextanchor = "start",
               showlegend = F) %>% 
       layout(
               yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE,showline = FALSE,showticklabels = FALSE),
               uniformtext = list(mode = "show")
               )

bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding the labels via `add_text` like so:

BTW: I put the vectors inside a df. Seems more natural to me.

```
library(plotly)

# Test long text and short bars
xValues <- c("loooooooooooooooooonnnnnngg","lonnnnnnnnnnggggggg",
             "dr3","dr4","dr5")
yValues <- c(0.5,1,2,0.22,10)

df <- data.frame(
  x = xValues,
  y = yValues
)

bar <- plot_ly(df, x = ~y, y = ~x, text = ~x) %>% 
  add_trace(
    type = 'bar',
    orientation = 'h',
    showlegend = F) %>% 
  add_text(x = 0.1, textposition = "middleright") %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE,showline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

bar
```

[image]

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to avoid hard coding any coordinates. There's also a space in front of the text that I would want to remove.

Comment: Sorry. You can remove the space before the labels by setting `x = 0`. I don't like hardcoding too. However, in this case I think that its acceptable to set x to 0 as bar plots naturally start (or should start (;) at zero.